# Why is my activeadmin header_renderer.rb breaking after upgrading to Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have customized activeadmin to render the main header nav based on user permissions. I give AdminUser a role and if role is "super" then the top nav shows up. I recently upgraded to ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.8 and I get the following error when trying to go to any active admin page.

```
NoMethodError in Admin/dashboard#index

Showing /Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bundler/gems/active_admin-3d6976ccf8a4/app/views/active_admin/dashboard/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: insert_tag view_factory.dashboard_page
Rails.root: /Users/mwallace/Development/dev/driftlab/driftlab/driftstack

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/admin/views/header_renderer.rb:13:in `add'
```

Here is what's in my app/admin/views/header_renderer.rb file. Commenting out the remove and add action fixes the error but my logic for to_html action no longer works if I comment out that code.

```
module ActiveAdmin    
class Menu 

        # def remove(name)
        #   item = self[name]
        #   return if item.nil?
        #   @items.delete(item)
        # end

        # def add(*args, &block)
        #   mitem = MenuItem.new(*args, &block)
        #   @items << mitem
        # end

      end

      module Views
        class HeaderRenderer
          def to_html
            title + global_nav? + utility_navigation
          end

          def global_nav?
            if current_admin_user.role == "super"
              puts "yep"
              global_navigation 
            else
              puts "nope"

            end
          end
        end

        class TabsRenderer
          def render_item(item)
            content_tag :li, :id => item.dom_id, :class => [("current" if current?(item)), ("has_nested" unless item.children.blank?)].compact.join(" ") do
              unless item.children.blank?
                link_to(item.name, item.url || "#") + render_nested_menu(item)
              else
                link_to item.name, item.url
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

@items is not initialized, so it is nil.
You have to initalize it, for example

```
@items ||= []
```

Comment: I tried adding @items ||= [] and now I get the following error "Showing /Users/mwallace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bundler/gems/active_admin-3d6976ccf8a4/app/views/active_admin/dashboard/index.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: insert_tag view_factory.dashboard_page"

Comment: I found the issue. I needed to look at the header.rb file and update my override code to match the latest activeadmin code. I'm pretty much monkey patching code to get what I want out of it at this point.